# Bypassing Lock on Generated Code in NetBeans 6.5?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.5

In NetBeans the GUI Builder generates code that is off limits to you from the editor.

I know you can switch to Design Mode and specify custom code and then enter edit in indirectly that way, but it's a pain to not be able to edit text that's 2 lines from your cursor.

Can I allow editing within those regions... I promise I'll be careful :)

Thanks.

Note: I don't want to lose code generation

Comment: From the answers, it seems that I misunderstood how it worked. I thought the untouchable code was the configuration info. I was unaware that it was really being generated from another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open it in an external editor, there are two possibilities:

- there is no guarantee that the changes you make will work (and not break anything) in the Netbeans UI Editor
- The next time you edit the file in Netbeans it will be regenerated.

Either way, probably not what you want. The best thing to do would probably be to make the whole design up in the gui editor and when you are happy with it, delete the comments and continue on.

[sarcasm]
With the drag and drop gui editor, what could you possibly want to change by hand anyway?
[/sarcasm] ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you open the .java files in Notepad or WordPad, you'll find pairs of comments that say

```
// GEN-BEGIN: <name of section>
...
// GEN-END: <name of section>
```

Delete those comments, and two things will happen.

1. You'll be able to edit anywhere in the file in NetBeans.
2. NetBeans will not be able to regenerate the file from the GUI editor.

So it can be done, but **don't do it unless you really mean it**.

---

EDIT: "Note: I don't want to lose code generation." Ok, let's see here.

1. You want to change what is generated.
2. You don't want to lose code generation.
3. You don't want to use the facilities NetBeans provides for adding custom code.

It sounds like you're wishing yourself trouble. :D

Comment: I know that. :) Was looking for something that didn't require me to blow away the existing code generation stuff.

Comment: Perhaps.  Even an "Open as Text" feature would do.

Comment: But even if you did open it as text, your changes would be destroyed the next time you changed the form.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. I extended JPanel with my own panel class and I was not able to pack it with the rest of UI. First I searched the web and I found your question. I was not able to find elegant solution to this problem.
Therefore, I decided to create another java class and copy NetBeans created code into it. It worked like a charm.
I agree, it would be nice if we can modify existing code like in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I copy the initcomponents() method, create my own method newInitComponents() paste the generated code, and override what needs to be overridden before i distribute the code. That way when a change is made in the editor, you can still copy paste the code into your new method. You keep the functionality without costing you the ability to override where necessary. Just call newInitComponents() in your constructor rather than the original. This is not the most efficient way of doing things, but it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try moving the `.form` file in

(project name)\src\(name of JFrame/JPanel).form

NetBeans will now see it as a `.java` file.
If you did not edit anything necessary for the GUI editor, you can move the `.form` file back into the `src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you subclass the class and redefine the method where this code is? Of course then you'll have to maintain the method over time as you make changes to the GUI.

You can maybe also look into AspectJ. It will modify the byte-code at build time and make the changes you define. Not sure if this gives you enough control over what code to change.

Comment: Don't want to change the code, just the IDE's behaviour.  Because I can make it work as is, but it's annoying.

Comment: You can write plugins for Netbeans. I've seen some tutorials around for doing that. Not sure if it's possible to change this behavior or how hard it would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [APT](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) you can rewrite source code at compile time. This way you can overwrite the code that's there at the moment. You could keep the new code in the same Java file along with comments to explain what is going on. [This tutorial](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17876) makes it pretty easy to get started. Copy that code, get it working, then tweak it to your liking. To find out where in the code the annotated method is call getPosition() on the Declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Go to design page and select any one of the fields. Right click on any selected field and choose Customizer Code , In Customizer Code change all default code to custom creation . Now you can edit your design code as you like...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple... the crappy UTF-8 did not let me compile one JasperReport (everything done by GUI).  So, I needed to change Project to iso-8859-1.  Result?  The project is messed up and some of the things to correct are in the blocked parts of the code.  So, I really NEED to edit those automatically generated parts.  When they are regenerated, they will be fine because the project is now iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Step # 1 Close the project in NetBeans

Step # 2 Delete the .form file from the source directory of your project

Reopen the project and it will be editable now!