# Dynamic Buttons in Netbeans Design View

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

I am developing a GUI using Swing and Netbeans Design features.  I'm a beginner to Netbeans and wondering if there is any way to 'hide' a button by calling a method or by changing any settings in GUI builder.  
In the design view, I did not notice any option(s) to modify buttons with a method, and the code generated in source view is protected which I cannot edit.

So, is there any way to modify or program how a Jbutton works?

Comment: :Code generated is locked?? You must be doing something wrong . The source code is very well editable while designing.

Comment: `Jbutton.setVisible(false)` will 'hide' it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bypass the locking of Netbeans code you can see how in this post [Bypassing Lock on Generated Code in NetBeans 6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450727/bypassing-lock-on-generated-code-in-netbeans-6-5) .

Now if just what you want is to hide a button that is very easy using

```
this.jButton1.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to unlock the source code.. It should not even be locked. Then find the button variable in the source code and hide it by writing:

```
ButtonNameHere.setVisible(false);
```

or if you just want to disable the button for a user, write

```
ButtonNameHere.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Not really.  You can simple switch to code mode and access the button like any normal object.  Sure it won't hide it in design mode, but hay...