# Netbeans GUI broken after Maven Transition (How do I change generated code that isn't part of a component?)

Tags: java, swing, maven, user-interface, netbeans

I'm trying to revive several applications that someone else wrote quite a while ago. I decided a good path was to get all of these in a good SCM system, and change the build style over to maven (for dependency management). I have successfully done the first part, and now I'm on step two.

My problem is that I can't get the application I'm working on to compile.

It was originally written using the NetBeans GUI builder (with Swing), and built using ANT (default nbproject build scripts). I successfully converted the project into a Maven project within NetBeans, but when I changed the document structure of the project to work with Maven, the structure changed from `package` to `main.java.package`. This caused me a good number of compile errors because most of the `Import` java statements were referencing `package` instead of `main.java.package`. I have fixed a lot of these issues with a simple find and replace operation; however, because the GUI parts of the application were created with the netbeans GUI builder (which generated code that cannot be modified in the source editor, I cannot fix references to `package.classname.class`.

Basically, switching to Maven has edited my package "path", but I can't change the generated GUI code manually, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this. Here's an example of two lines of problematic generated code:

```
>javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(gls_desktop.GLSapp.class).getContext().getActionMap(GLSview.class, this);
>org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap resourceMap =org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(gls_desktop.GLSapp.class).getContext().getResourceMap(GLSview.class);
```

The problem is the `gls_desktop.classname.class` part. I need to change it to `main.java.gls_desktop.classname.class`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. (Because this code doesn't apply to a particular component, but rather the application as a whole.)

How do I change generated code in netbeans that doesn't belong to a component?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find a "safer" way to edit the generated code, which is the primary reason that I posted this question, but I still never found a method of changing the generated code within Netbeans.

I did end up solving my issue by using Notepad++ to edit my files, as described in this SO question: [Bypassing Lock on Generated Code in NetBeans 6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450727/bypassing-lock-on-generated-code-in-netbeans-6-5)

The errors I was having now appear to be resolved, but I cannot yet see any side-effects (because some other errors have still kept me from a successful build).

Summary: Use an External Text Editor, but be careful because you could break the GUI Builder.